# Windows SBS 2011 Essentials - "network device driver was not found"

Tags: windows-sbs-2011

I am installing Windows server and at the very last stage it says: "Errors occurred during installation. A network device driver was not found. Install the appropriate drivers for your network device, and then restart the server."
An option is given, to 'Install network drivers'. When I click on that, 'Device Manager' window comes up.  In 'Other devices' I have 'Ethernet Controller', 'Network Controller', etc.. Does anyone know where this is going? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In order to proceed with the installation, you need to install drivers for your networking hardware. Depending on the hardware you’ve got you may have some CDs containing the needed drivers so you have to plug those in, double click on each device that is in “Other devices” and update the driver pointing explorer dialog to that CD. If there is no hardcopy for the drivers you will need to go to the manufacturer's website and download those drivers from there. After this is done you will be able to proceed with the installation.

Here is the exact manual how to install the drivers: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc626158(v=ws.10).aspx

Hope it helps.